# Using IMPORTHTML and/or IMPORTXML to extract table data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Using the table on https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/minor-league?sort=23,1&pageitems=10000000000000&pg=0, I am not able to extract the table data into Google Sheets. I have tried `IMPORTHTML(B2,"table",1)` - where B2 reference the URL - and `=IMPORTXML(B2,"//*[@id='root-the-board']/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table")` as well after copying the `<table>` XPATH from the inspect console. Errors include Imported content does not have query with given index and Imported Content is Empty, respectively.

Comment: This site is populated by Javascript. Even though the data may appear in the browser, it can't be scraped because it is not a static value. [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115665/196152) is an important resource because it explains the how and why of this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

The table you're trying to import is dynamically loaded. This data is loaded by JavaScript, therefore is not retrievable by IMPORT functions in Google Sheets. If you disable JavaScript and reload this site, you will notice that you're not able to retrieve the table. You can check this by clicking the lock icon next to the URL bar > 'Site settings' > set JavaScript to 'Block'. You can refer to this [article](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/import-social-media-statistics/#notWorking) for more details.